# Dynamic Parameter won't appear when a static parameter uses SecureString

Tags: powershell, function, parameters, powershell-core

Other scripts with dynamic parameters have never given me any issues. The one thing that is different is this is the first time I am using a SecureString type on a static parameter.

If I call this paramenter, the Dynamic one will not appear. I'm not doing anything special to hide the dynamic parameter. It should always appear. The issue appears on both 5.1 and PowerShell core.

I would be interested to know if there is a solution to this problem.

The dynamic parameter looks at available system services and allows you to enter only those services as part of the parameter.

This is only an example to replicate what I'm experiencing. Calling the Name parameter and supplying the information has no effect on the Service Dynamic Parameter. As soon as Password Parameter is called, you cannot call the Service Parameter if you hadn't already.

```
function test-command {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        $Name,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [SecureString]
        $Password
    )

    DynamicParam {
        $ParameterName = 'Service'
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]

        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $true
        $ParameterAttribute.HelpMessage = "Parameter Help."

        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)

        $arrSet = (Get-Service).Name
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)

        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $AttributeAlias = New-Object System.Management.Automation.AliasAttribute('s', 'Serv')
        $AttributeCollection.Add($AttributeAlias)

        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [array], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ParameterName, $RuntimeParameter)
        return $RuntimeParameterDictionary
    }

begin {
    $Service = $PsBoundParameters[$ParameterName]
}
process {
    $Service
}
end {

}
```

}

Yes, I could call Service Parameter first and then the remaining ones, but if there is an answer as to why it's behaving this way I'd certainly like to know. Plus, if someone else uses my script, they wouldn't automatically know to do this. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you show us how are you passing the argument to `-Password` ? If you store a `securestring` instance and then do `-Password $mySecureString` then `-Service` will show without any problem: https://i.imgur.com/ojlJdmp.png

Comment: Actually, I tried that as well. I noticed you're doing this in VSCode. Try it in Terminal or in a Powershell console.

Test-Command -Name 'Name' -Password $SecureVariable.

Comment: ahhh yeah, clearly doesnt work in windows powershell. works on core tho. https://i.imgur.com/hZhapsM.png

Comment: I'm using core as well and it doesn't work there either. Just tried it in vsCode and it doesn't work. Not sure why it is for you.

https://imgur.com/a/WAITlcM

Comment: ok i see what you mean, its failing on `7.3.1` thats unfortunate. in `7.4.0-preview.1` it should work

Comment: Interesting. So it is a bug that's being resolved in the next release.

Comment: Im not sure if it could be considered a bug, I can agree that autocompletion has been improved greatly in latest versions but a bug would mean that you can't use `-Service` which you can in any version, its just that autocompletion is not helping you except in preview

Comment: Is there any reason you're just not using the autocompletor attribute for this? `[ArgumentCompletor({(Get-Service).Name})]` instead?

Comment: It's not available in PS 5.1. If possible, I'd like it to work in older versions as well.

Comment: @Jessie, `[ArgumentCompleter]` _is_ available in WinPS - it is `[ArgumentCompletions]` that isn't.